# Efficient extract specific data from a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, slice

I am trying to extract many different individual points from a 2000x2000 matrix (`bigger_matrix`). I do not need all of the matrix (so I can't use `melt`) but I need to extract specific instances and store it in a new pre-specified dataframe (`output_data_frame`). Currently I do this as a loop i R:

```
#example data
bigger_matrix=matrix(0,nrow =5,ncol=5)
rownames(bigger_matrix)=c('10001','10002','10009','100101467','10011')
colnames(bigger_matrix)=c('10001','10002','10009','100101467','10011')
output_data_frame=data.frame(nrow=7)
output_data_frame$Var1=c("10002",'10009','100101467','100129543','100129842','100131017','100131827')
```

output_data_frame$Var2=c("10001","10001","10001","10001","10001","10001","10001")

```
for (i in 1:nrow(output_data_frame)){
    p1=as.character(output_data_frame[i,1])
    p2=as.character(output_data_frame[i,2])
    output_data_framef[i,'value']=bigger_matrix[p1,p2]
    #count to monitor progress
    print(count)
    count=count+1
}
```

This procedure is very slow. Does anyone know how to do this more efficiently?

**Edit**
`output_data_frame` looks like this (I want to fill in the `NA`s)

```
row.names   Var1    Var2    value   
1   1   10002   10001   NA  
2   2   10009   10001   NA  
3   3   100101467   10001   NA  
4   5   100129543   10001   NA
5   6   100129842   10001   NA
6   7   100131017   10001   NA
7   8   100131827   10001   NA
```

`bigger_matrix` looks like this:

```
row.names   10001   10002   10009   100101467   10011
1   10001   0   0   0   0   0
2   10002   0   0   0   0   0
3   10009   0   0   0   0   0
4   100101467   0   0   0   0   0
5   10011   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Can't you just subset the first and second columns as `output_data_frame[,1:2]`? Can you provide a smaller matrix that can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I edited the question to provided more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the `Extract` manual page. Assuming you use only row names and column names that actually exist in your matrix (unlike your example), you can extract the values directly:

```
x <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
colnames(x) <- as.character(1:5)
rownames(x) <- as.character(1:5)
x
#   1  2  3  4  5
# 1 1  6 11 16 21
# 2 2  7 12 17 22
# 3 3  8 13 18 23
# 4 4  9 14 19 24
# 5 5 10 15 20 25
rows <- c("1", "1", "3", "5")
cols <-c("5", "4", "1", "2")
idx <- cbind(rows, cols)
valx <- x[idx]
data.frame(rows, cols, valx)
  rows cols valx
# 1    1    5   21
# 2    1    4   16
# 3    3    1    3
# 4    5    2   10
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I Did not know you could extract many values from matrices at one time.